# how to get more that +10/11 LatLng values from markers

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have an array with localizations ("street, city, postalcode, province, country").
I want to have a string with all Lat and Lng values for each localization, like this ("#lat.value|lng.value#lat2.value|lng2.value.." etc). I use for this Google API Geocoder. But Geocoder has a annoying limit 10~11 localizations once. How can I get about 100 lat&lng values for 100 localization? I tried sleep() funcion, but this doesn't work. This is my function in js.

```
                function sleep(time){
                   time = time * 1000;
                   var start = (new Date()).getTime();
                   while(true){
                      alarm = (new Date()).getTime();
                      if(alarm - start > time){ break; }
                   }
                }

(..)
                var mystring = "";
                var address = <%=testing %>
                var arrayaddress = address.split("%");

                for (var i = 0; i < arrayaddress.length-1; i++) {
                    sleep(0);
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': arrayaddress[i]}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                        var zmiennalat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                        var zmiennalng = marker.getPosition().lng();
                        mystring = mystring + "#" + zmiennalat + "|" + zmiennalng;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        mystring = mystring + "#" + "er" + "|" + "er";
                        //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                    if (i == arrayaddress.length-1) {
                       var dsa = mystring;
                       document.getElementById("<%=hfWysokosc.ClientID%>").value = mystring;
                       document.getElementById("<%=hfSzerokosc.ClientID%>").value = dsa;
                       document.getElementById("<%=UpdateButton1.ClientID %>").click();
                    }

                    }); 
                 } // for
```

Then, result is for example:

> er|er#34.42342|16.4323#23.32131|43.54545# etc..

always at first localizations is error with decoding (if more than 10 places in array). Why?
Why not at last localizations?

Resuming: How can i get more than 10 lat|lng values in this stirng with this loop?

Thanks!

EDIT

thanks, that work nice !

But there is another problem. string Mystring is showing very slowly.. how to repair it? and it is refreshing when marker is setting on map - maybe it is not a problem, but for 100-150 markers i have to wait a few long minutes to get Mystring value.. Is it any posibility to show more faster Mystring value?

```
                        var mystring = "";
                    var address = <%=testing %>
                    alert(address);
                    var arrayaddress = address.split("%");

                    (function nextStep(i){
                    if( i >= arrayaddress.length-1 ){
                        return;
                    }
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': arrayaddress[i]}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                        var zmiennalat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                        var zmiennalng = marker.getPosition().lng();
                        mystring = mystring + zmiennalat + "|" + zmiennalng + "#";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        mystring = mystring + "er" + "|" + "er" + "#";
                        //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                    }); 
                    setTimeout(function(){   nextStep(i+1);   }, 800); 
                       var dsa = mystring;
                       document.getElementById("<%=hfSzerokosc.ClientID%>").value = dsa;
                       document.getElementById("<%=UpdateButton1.ClientID %>").click();    
                })(0);
```

**UPDATE**

```
                    function nextStep(i){
                    if( i >= arrayaddress.length-1 ){
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    // code
                    
                    }); 
                    setTimeout(function(){   nextStep(i+1);   }, 1000);     
                };
```

then

```
<button type="button" onclick="nextStep(0)">Click Me!</button>
```

and error is:

> nextStep is not defined

what is wrong?

Comment: That "sleep()" function is a crime against humanity.

Comment: earlier i had setTimeout function, i tried with everything, but.. ok, ok, my bad :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of for-loop, try this:

```
//...............
//...............

var mystring = "";
var address = <%=testing %>
var arrayaddress = address.split("%");

//Modification-----BEGIN
(function nextStep(i){
    if( i >= arrayaddress.length-1 ){
        return;
    }

    //-----------------
    //for-loop body here
    //------------------

    //
    setTimeout(function(){   nextStep(i+1);   }, 500);       
})(0);
//Modification-----END

//...............
//...............
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to run `nextStep` function,only when button will be clicked,then modify above code like this:

```
function nextStep(i){
    /////   
};
```

Then,when `onclick` will be triggered, simply call `nextStep(0)`.

Comment: thanks, that work very nice! but there is another problem - please, see it at first post, after "edit". Greetings !

Comment: @whoah You can configure requests speed,by changing delay of `setTimeout` method. To speed up, set delay, for example, to `100`,and so on...

Comment: yea, i know. But for example - this 100 markers is on the map, but i have to wait a few minutes till the Mystring will show value.

Comment: @whoah If your `latlng` array always have same values,that is, it is *static*, then you can do your 100-150 requests, and store responsed data somewhere in your server(in database,file,etc..). Then by just one request retrieve all the data from your storage( data base, some file, etc...).

Comment: okay, that's works ! But there is last question - how can I run function nextStep only when i click the button? not at reloading page?

Comment: ok, in my 1 post I add some information - please, look at it.

Comment: @whoah As `nextStep` declared inside of the other function, it is not visible from outside of that function.You need to declare it as a global ,like this -> `window.nextStep = function(i){`, instead of `function nextStep(i){`

Comment: ok, and then when i have window.nextStep = function(i){, how can I named OnClick event?  onclick="function(0)" ? or how?

Comment: @whoah NO, the calling procedure is same `nextStep(0)`